# jQuery delete all table rows except the selected one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to come up with the best way to use jQuery to delete all the rows except for the one selected. I've done some searching and I've seen several posts about deleting all records or all records except the first or last row but nothing on deleting all but the one selected.

The scenario would be searching for a list of employees which would return maybe 5 records. Then there would be a "Select" button and when you click on that button it would remove all `<tbody>` rows except for that one. Actually from there my idea is to not only remove the rows but then to hide the "Select" button and display a text box as well as displaying a "Add" button below the table to add the employees with the item entered in the textbox.

I've thought about putting a hidden field on each row that has an row #, pass that row index to a jQuery function and then loop through all of the Tbody.Tr and remove if it doesn't match the row index passed in?

Another thought would be to put an `Onclick` on each of the "Select" buttons and then in the function use "this" to for reference to the row but then I don't know how to effectively say `"remove all but $this row"`.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Employee ID</th>
            <th>Position Title</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.listEmployee)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.FirstName</td>
                <td>@item.LastName</td>
                <td>@item.EmployeeId</td>
                <td>@item.PositionTitle</td>
                <td>
                    <button id="btnSelect" class="btn btn-sm">Select</button>
                    <input id="txtCaseNo" type="text" style="display:none;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: FYI, ids need to be singular

Comment: You have 2 approches, try them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ids need to be singular so `id="btnSelect"` is not going to work. Make it a class or name.

So select the TR and select the siblings and you can remove it.

```js
$("tbody").on("click", "button", function() {  //bind the click to the buttons
  var button = $(this) //get what was clicked
  $(this).closest("tr") //select the TR
    .siblings() //get the other TRS
    .remove() // um, remove them
  button.hide()  //hide your button
  button.siblings().removeAttr('hidden')  //show the input
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-sm">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Employee ID</th>
      <th>Position Title</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A@item.FirstName</td>
      <td>@item.LastName</td>
      <td>@item.EmployeeId</td>
      <td>@item.PositionTitle</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btnSelect btn btn-sm">Select</button>
        <input name="txtCaseNo" type="text" hidden />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B@item.FirstName</td>
      <td>@item.LastName</td>
      <td>@item.EmployeeId</td>
      <td>@item.PositionTitle</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btnSelect btn btn-sm">Select</button>
        <input name="txtCaseNo" type="text" hidden />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C@item.FirstName</td>
      <td>@item.LastName</td>
      <td>@item.EmployeeId</td>
      <td>@item.PositionTitle</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btnSelect btn btn-sm">Select</button>
        <input name="txtCaseNo" type="text" hidden />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>D@item.FirstName</td>
      <td>@item.LastName</td>
      <td>@item.EmployeeId</td>
      <td>@item.PositionTitle</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btnSelect btn btn-sm">Select</button>
        <input name="txtCaseNo" type="text" hidden />
      </td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't think about using CSS for the selector and then obviously I didn't know about the .siblings.remove. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not filter on your Model.listEmployee on the id of the selected row? This is assuming your current set up is reactive.

Ie:

```
const new_list = old_list.filter(item => item.id !== selected_id)
```